# How to test component error handling with observable service

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine, angular-test

### Context

I'm trying to test a component. In another post I asked about testing the direct function call. Here I'm focusing, using same example component, on the error handling of my component.

I want to test, when my service returns an observable error, that my component properly calls console.error(error).

**How to "create" this error trigger and test my component handles it properly. I heard about spies could do that but I don't know where to setup this spy.**

I want to simulate the case where the http request on the service could fail. For any reason or any error code.

### Code

Here is the code for component, stub service and my spec files.

#### Component

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';

import { UserManagementService } from '../../shared/services/global.api';
import { UserListItemComponent } from './user-list-item.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-user-list',
  templateUrl: './user-list.component.html'
})
export class UserListComponent implements OnInit {
  public userList = [];

  constructor(
    private _userManagementService: UserManagementService,    
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getUserList();
  }

  onRefreshUserList() {
    this.getUserList();
  }

  getUserList(notifyWhenComplete = false) {
    this._userManagementService.getListUsers().subscribe(
      result => {
        this.userList = result.objects;
      },
      error => {
        console.error(error); // That's the part of my component I want to test     
      },
      () => {
        if (notifyWhenComplete) {
          console.info('Notification');
        }
      }
    );
  }
}
```

#### Component spec file

```
import { NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import {
  async,
  fakeAsync,
  ComponentFixture,
  TestBed,
  tick,
  inject
} from '@angular/core/testing';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

// Components
import { UserListComponent } from './user-list.component';

// Services
import { UserManagementService } from '../../shared/services/global.api';
import { UserManagementServiceStub } from '../../testing/services/global.api.stub';

let comp:    UserListComponent;
let fixture: ComponentFixture<UserListComponent>;
let service: UserManagementService;

describe('UserListComponent', () => {
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [UserListComponent],
      imports: [],
      providers: [
        {
          provide: UserManagementService,
          useClass: UserManagementServiceStub
        }
      ],
      schemas: [ NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  tests();
});

function tests() {
  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(UserListComponent);
    comp = fixture.componentInstance;

    service = TestBed.get(UserManagementService);
  });

  it(`should be initialized`, () => {
    expect(fixture).toBeDefined();
    expect(comp).toBeDefined();
  });

  it(`should get the user List after ngOnInit`, async(() => {
    fixture.detectChanges();

    expect(comp.userList.length).toBe(3, 'user list exists after init');
  }));
}
```

#### Stub service

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

export class UserManagementServiceStub {
  getListUsers() {
    return Observable.from([      
      {
        count: 3, 
        objects: 
        [
          {
            id: "7f5a6610-f59b-4cd7-b649-1ea3cf72347f",
            name: "user 1",
            group: "any"
          },
          {
            id: "d6f54c29-810e-43d8-8083-0712d1c412a3",
            name: "user 2",
            group: "any"
          },
          {
            id: "2874f506-009a-4af8-8ca5-f6e6ba1824cb", 
            name: "user 3",
            group: "any"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]);
  }
}
```

Comment: The context is the same but question is not. I don't want to mess two type of questions in a single post. If I place everything in a single post with two question and the people answers only on one question/problem, how to mark the proper answer as accepted one...

Comment: Not a duplicate of calls on spy post. Total different problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I'm correct in understanding that you just need a way to return an error from a stubbed service, you can just create a separate stub which returns an Observable error, and then use that in the test that checks for error handling:

```
export class UserManagementServiceErrorStub {
  getListUsers() {
    return Observable.throw(new Error('Test error'));
  }
}
```

There is a really nice article on testing Angular services using Observables here:
https://web.archive.org/web/20191214083526/http://www.zackarychapple.guru/angular2/2016/11/25/angular2-testing-services.html

**Update - 01/06/2019 for RxJS 6**

```
import { throwError } from 'rxjs'; 

class UserManagementServiceErrorStub {
  getListUsers() {
    return throwError(new Error('Test error'));
  }
}
```

Comment: For latest version of rxjs, it's `throwError` imported from rxjs, instead of `Observable.throw`

Comment: The link to the article seems to have been hijacked

Comment: thanks @vonec - updated with a waybackmachine cached version of the original